# TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined Discord.js

Tags: node.js

I'm currently in problem with Discord.js, it's saying: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined.

msg.guild.id
^

It's just sending that error, code:

```
client.on('message', (message, msg) => {
    if(db.get(`${msg.guild.id}_prefix`)) {
      var prefix = defaultPrefix;
    } else { 
        var prefix = db.get(`${msg.guild.id}_prefix`); 
    }
    if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + `ping`)) {
        msg.channel.send(`Fetching Latency...`).then((m) => {
        const ping = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Pong! `)
        .addFields( { name: `API Latency`, value: `${client.ws.ping}ms` },
                    { name: `Bot Latency`, value: `${msg.createdTimestamp - m.createdTimestamp}ms` } )
            m.delete()
           msg.channel.send(ping)
    })}
});
```

**Please help me if you could**

Answer (score 1):

Normally `client.on('message', (message, msg) => {}` only take one output as you can see here : [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message)

So you should only use `message`